# Java - Find first and last 2 distinct value

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I hava a list contains values like below,

```
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(10,10,10,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6);
```

From there I need to find first(10,9) and last(6,7) distinct value's total sum and count.

Expected OP :

```
First : Count=7, Sum=66
Last :  Count=13, Sum=87
```

How to achieve this using java 8?

Code I tried :

```
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(10,10,10,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6);
List<Integer> first = data.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()); //here I am trying get first distinct values(10,10,10,9,9,9,9)
List<Integer> last = data.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());//here I am trying get last distinct values(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6)
int firstSum = first.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
long firstCount = first.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).count();
int lastSum = last.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
long lastCount = last.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).count();
System.out.println("First Sum:"+firstSum+" Count"+firstCount);
System.out.println("Last Sum:"+lastSum+" Count"+lastCount);
```

Comment: *How to achieve this using java 8* by writing some code... but either way, it's very difficult to help you here since this is very un-clear

Comment: You tagged your question java-stream, but streams are poorly suited for what you are asking. I’d probably use old-fashioned loops.

Answer (score 2):

You could group the numbers by value and count using `Stream` to `LinkedHashMap`.

```
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6);

Map<Integer, Long> map = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());

int a1 = keys.get(0);
int a2 = keys.get(1);
int b1 = keys.get(keys.size() - 1);
int b2 = keys.get(keys.size() - 2);

System.out.format("First : Count=%d, Sum=%d\n", map.get(a1) + map.get(a2), a1 * map.get(a1) + a2 * map.get(a2));
System.out.format("Last : Count=%d, Sum=%d\n", map.get(b1) + map.get(b2), b1 * map.get(b1) + b2 * map.get(b2));
```

Comment: But OP is wrong for Arrays.asList(10,10,10,9,9,9,9,8,8,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6); here we need to omit 9 from 8,9,9,9,8 because its not first distinct 9.

Comment: It only works correctly if the list is sorted, as in the question. Apart from that it’s well thought out.

Comment: For not sorted list, do use ‘TreeMap’ instead

Comment: Wrong, @oleg.cherednik. That won’t omit the 9s as MMMMS asks.

Answer (score 1):

Use loops.

First in a loop find the first element that isn’t equal to the first element in the list. If none is found, issue a message and stop. Then in a loop find the index of the first element that isn’t equal to any of those two, or the end of the list. Now you know how wide a range you need to cover for the first two distinct values. Now you *may* use a stream and `limit` for counting and summing, or one more loop.

Do similarly for the last two distinct values, only looping from the far end of the list.

If the list hasn’t got good random access, use a `ListIterator`.

Streams are not suited for your task. At least not when it comes to an unsorted list, as in your comment to another answer. Streams are for situation where the processing of each element does not depend on the elements that come before or after. In your task, a 9 may be included or omitted from the count and sum depending on whether an 8 comes before it in the list or not.

### Edit: Streams for the academic exercise

I admit it became a challenge for me. Here’s a solution using streams. I don’t recommend it, I stand by what I said above. It may even be used to show how complex a stream solution will be.

```
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9,
            8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6);
    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No elements");
    } else {
        int firstDistinct = data.get(0);
        OptionalInt secondDistinctOpt = data.stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .dropWhile(i -> i == firstDistinct)
                .findFirst();
        assert secondDistinctOpt.stream().noneMatch(sd -> sd == firstDistinct);
        Optional<IntSummaryStatistics> statsOpt = secondDistinctOpt.stream()
                .mapToObj(secondDistinct -> data.stream()
                                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                .takeWhile(i -> i == firstDistinct || i == secondDistinct)
                                .summaryStatistics())
                .findAny();
        statsOpt.ifPresentOrElse(
                stats -> System.out.println("Count = " + stats.getCount() + " Sum = "+ stats.getSum()),
                () -> System.out.println("No 2 distinct values"));
    }
```

> Count = 7 Sum = 66

For the last two distinct values you may reverse the list using `Collections.reverse` and repeat.

**Further edit:** I deliberately took your example list from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098995/java-find-first-and-last-2-distinct-value/55101058?noredirect=1#comment96943910_55099959) rather than the list from your question to demonstrate that the 9s that come after the first 8 are not included in the sum and count.

Comment: Input mismatch from question, though the output remained same :)